# Concat multiple MATCH criteria in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So in Excel, we know it's possible to test against multiple criteria via concatenation, like this:

```
MATCH(criteria1&criteria2, Range(), 0)
```

where `criteria1` and `criteria2` are 2 separate criteria.

I'm trying to automate this thing in Excel VBA, like this:

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(criteria1 + "&" + criteria2, Range(), 0)
```

My question is, how do I replicate the same concatenation of criteria with the ampersand, in VBA form? In the version above, Excel keeps telling me it can't use the Match function of the WorkSheetFunction class, which I'm attributing to the failed concatenation attempt above. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, and here's a link to a Microsoft Knowledge Base article about using multiple criteria in `MATCH()`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/59482

EDIT: I realized I wasn't putting 2 ranges to correspond with my 2 criteria. The problem is I don't know how to concatenate 2 ranges, because mine are in the form:

```
Range(Cells(1,columnIndex),Cells(rowCount,columnIndex))
```

as opposed to `A1:A200`. Any ideas on how to convert, or to concat the ranges in their current form?

Comment: You can use `Address()` to convert your Range objects to a string version.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Sub dural()
    crit1 = "find "
    crit2 = "happiness"
    N = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(crit1 & crit2, Range("A1:A10"), 0)
    MsgBox N
End Sub
```

with, say **A3** containing:

*find happiness*

**EDIT#1:**

Consider the case of multiple criteria in several columns.  For example:

[image: demo]

and we want **VBA** to retrieve the name of a *small, black, dog*

without **VBA** in a worksheet cell we can use:

```
=INDEX(D1:D100,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100="dog")*(B1:B100="small")*(C1:C100="black")*ROW(1:100)),1)
```

to get the name *Oscar*

we can use the same formula in **VBA**

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim s As String, s2 As String
    s = "INDEX(D1:D100,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100=""dog"")*(B1:B100=""small"")*(C1:C100=""black"")*ROW(1:100)),1)"
    s2 = Evaluate(s)
    MsgBox s2
End Sub
```

Comment: The thing is I'm testing against multiple criteria that both have to be present; for example, it'd be Match(date & ID, Range(), 0), and the match would have to have the correct date AND ID, not the concatenation of the two.

Comment: Are you taking about criteria in two *cells,* so **A4** must have the correct date and **B4** have the correct ID and then return **4?**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - see link in the original question

Comment: Yeah @Gary'sStudent, that's what I mean. I realized the problem was I wasn't putting in 2 ranges since I have 2 criteria, like the example shows. The problem is, I don't know how to convert my Range(Cells(),Cells()) range to a "A2:A10" style range.

Comment: I would use the same formula I would use in a worksheet cell....I like **SUMPRODUCT()** ...see my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't readily map to a VBA implementation, but you can cheat a bit using Evaluate:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim v1, v2, f

    v1 = "y"
    v2 = 11

    Sheet1.Names.Add Name:="X", RefersTo:=v1
    Sheet1.Names.Add Name:="Y", RefersTo:=v2

    f = "MATCH(X&Y,$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5, 0)"

    Debug.Print Sheet1.Evaluate(f)

End Sub
```

or skipping the names:

```
Sub Tester2()

    Const F_TEMPL As String = "MATCH(""{V1}""&""{V2}"",$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5, 0)"
    Dim v1, v2, f

    f = Replace(F_TEMPL, "{V1}", "x")
    f = Replace(f, "{V2}", 12)

    Debug.Print Sheet1.Evaluate(f)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to send the `MATCH` argument body as a string. The '+' does not concatenate.

```
WorksheetFunction.Match(criteria1 & "&" & criteria2, Range(), 0)
```

Should concatenate the two values and execute the match.