# VBA Index and Match

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to write a code that uses my current workbook and opens up another workbook and then compares data from the two using a Index and Macth lookup comparing two types of criteria.

```
Sub BCReport()
Dim wbO As Workbook
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wbJune As Workbook, wsJune As Worksheet

Set wbO = ThisWorkbook
Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Combined")

Set wbJune = Workbooks.Open("J:\15_0615_P.xls")
Set wsJune = wbJune.Sheets("Combined")

Set myRange = wsO.Range("AI2:AI3000")
Set myCPTRange = wsO.Range("I2:I3000")
Set myALLRange = ws0.Range("V2:V3000")

Set JuneCPTRange = wsJune.Range("I2:I3000")
Set JuneALLRange = wsJune.Range("V2:V3000")
Set JuneMCPGRange = wsJune.Range("AI2:AI3000")

For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count

test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(JuneMCPGRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myCPTRange.Cells(i, j).Value & myALLRange.Cells(i,j).value, JuneCPTRange & JuneALLRange, 0))
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

What I'm doing esentially is I have a file from July (my current file) and a file from June (the one I hope up in the code).  I want to look through "CPT" Codes and their correspsonding "ALL" amount and search through my previous spreadsheet from June and if any lines match in both criteria I want to output what I have in the JuneMCPGRange into the cell on my original document (that is in line with the CPT and ALL amounts that are currently being looked up)

If anyone has any assistance that would be great!

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is your actual problem? Is there an error? If so, at what line and what is the error description?

Comment: Run-Time Error 424: Object Required,  I forgot to add in my code above me defining the Ranges as Ranges, but still I'm getting the object error

Comment: Guessing that your `Match` function is returning an error, so it's returning a `Nothing` object, which would give you the 424 error.  Try to execute the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` in the Immediate window.

Comment: Do you think It's because of how I definied the range in the begining?  Leaving it just JuneMCPGRange?  I mean I defined that above so i figured it would understand the location of where to look

Comment: No, it would be expected to return an `#N/A` if the value is not found by the Match fucntion.

Answer (score 1):

These two worksheet references are different...

```
Set myCPTRange = wsO.Range("I2:I3000")
Set myALLRange = ws0.Range("V2:V3000")
```

If you always use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, you can save yourself from this type of error.

**EDIT:**
I don't think you can run a multi-value MATCH lookup like that in VBA: best you could do is the use the Range addresses to construct the appropriate formula, then use wsO.Evaluate(yourformulahere) to run it and get the output.

See e.g. last answer here :  [Concat multiple MATCH criteria in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787010/concat-multiple-match-criteria-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that and was hoping it fixed it, but I'm still getting the object error